# No output from OhNetGen.exe? (whether code or error message!)

Tags: .net, mono, code-generation, upnp

I am trying to evaluate OhNet for a Set-top Box UPnP Control Point solution on the an iOS platform.

I want to use OhNetGen to generate some custom proxies for the UPnP Control Point stack. I am unable to get any output from the tool, whether generated code or error messages!

I am on a Win7 x64 platform and I have tried downloading pre-built ohNet versions for both x86 and x64, both debug and release builds. I have also tried updating to the latest version of WinSDK which I think gives me .NET v4. When calling OhNetGen.exe with the requisite arguments, the behaviour is the same with any binaries.

```
ohNetGen.exe --language=c --stack=cp --xml="c:\Program Files (x86)\UPnP\Developer Tools for UPnP Technologies\Sample Service Descriptions\AV_AVTransport-0.9.xml" --output=c:\Resources\UPNP\ohNet\proxies --domain=urn:schemas-upnp-org --type=AV_AVTransport-0.9 --version=1
```

The command takes time before exiting, but nothing is output. Neither generated proxy code nor any error messages to say what failed. Since I have some custom UPnP services on my device, if I want to use OhNet (and I do) it is essential that I can generate the Proxies to control them!

Any help or advice you can offer is appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following some advice and some trials, I did manage to generate the proxies using OhNetGen. Here are the steps:

1. Unpack the x64 release binary download.
2. In the folder ohNet-Windows-x64-release-dev\lib\t4, create a new path OpenHome\Net\T4\Templates
3. Copy all the *.tt files from lib\t4 to lib\t4\OpenHome\Net\T4\Templates
4. Put the XML Service templates to a sub directory relative to OhNetGen.exe
5. Create an Output directory for the proxies that is a sub-directory relative to OhNetGen.exe
6. At a command prompt, change directory to lib\t4
7. Give relative paths for the xml and output options
8. You should now be able to run ohNetGen.exe with lib\t4 as your current directory.

Just for reference, these are the args I used:

```
ohNetGen.exe --language=c --stack=cp --xml=config\EventServices.xml --output=proxies\ --domain=schemas-upnp-org --type=EventServices --version=1
```

**Edit: Entering the domain as I did above causes OhNetGen to generate a proxy with dashes in the function names. Clearly these are invalid names in C (and C++). You should enter the domain in domain.org format and OhNetGen will handle any necessary translation. See below:**

```
ohNetGen.exe --language=c --stack=cp --xml=config\EventServices.xml --output=proxies\ --domain=upnp.org --type=EventServices --version=1
```

Hope this helps...

Doug

Comment: For the record, --domain=upnp.org would be preferable in your command line.  This canonical form of the domain will be translated into UPnP form where required by the T4 scripts.